# Fix column length for use with the 'cor' function

Tags: r, r-corrplot

Here's my simple problem:

```
length(Helps_Me.Family)
[1] 4
length(Patient_Help)
[1] 5

 cor(Patient_Help, Helps_Me.Family)
```

> Error in cor(Patient_Help, Helps_Me.Family) : incompatible dimensions

Comment: Please [edit your question as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: If those are vectors, then you should know that correlation is a concept between vectors of the same length, this is not unique to R. If those are frames, then you might need to explain what you expect to see out of that call. Regardless, to get more help, you will need to edit your question with more context, as suggested by NelsonGon.